# How formal is SVP or S.V.P. ?

Tags: standard, politesse, correspondance

Is it frowned upon to use “*S'il vous plaît*” instead of *SVP* or *S.V.P.* in formal letters?

Comment: Where exactly in a formal letter ? I'd answer **no**, as I would ask the opposite question : *Is it frowned upon to abreviate it instead of using the full form ?* — but I'm no good at formal letters.

Comment: An abbreviated SVP is often found at the end of tactless authoritative requests. I believe it could be considered rude, unless a real lack of space can explain it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're going to write some form of it, use “*s'il vous plaît* ”. Abbreviating it would appear like authoritative rudeness in full text (unlike in formulas like “*Tournez SVP*” near the bottom of the page, for instance).

Now, depending on how you phrase it, it can easily seem you're begging for someone's will, which may not be what you want to express. Alternatives could go :

- *Pourriez-vous …*
- *Je vous serai[(s)](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic5925-orthographe-de-je-vous-serais-reconnaissant-de.html) obligé de bien vouloir …*
- *Veuillez … [, s'il vous plaît]*

depending on how formal it is, and especially on the balance of powers.

Comment: Yeah I ended up going with "Veuillez...". It sounds nice and doesn't seem too "needy" ... if that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: *Veuillez* should come with *very* big warnings ! *Veuillez accepter ceci* is fine but *Veuillez faire ceci* sounds very *very* authoritative. For example “Veuillez me répondre rapidement.” alone is a commandment, “s'il vous plaît” would only make it slightly less painful to read. (If a reason is provided though, it might become acceptable.)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Indeed, all depends on what comes after. There's “ *Veillez remplir* (whatnot)”, in the authoritative but acceptable domain, also. Depending on situations, sounding needy can be just as undesirable as sounding authoritative, so it's hard to go further whithout being more specific.

Comment: Je pense qu'il y a deux exceptions: * TSVP écrit seul en fin de page * RSVP comme statut de réponse à une invitation

Answer (score 4):

In formal letters, I don't use “*s'il vous plait*” nor any abbreviate form. “*S'il vous plait*” is in my opinion more frequently used in oral conversations, for example when you buy bread. Possibly in an e-mail…

Comment: I must say I agree with this answer. However, peut-être auriez-vous l'aimable obligence de proposer des alternatives ?